# Call Action Method on button click ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get user input in button `click`. 
When user insert number and press `Check`, it needs to return `xml` data type. 
So in my `controller` I create `function` which will return a data for passing `ID`

```
[ResponseType(typeof(AKONTA))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAKONTA(string id)
        {
            AKONTA aKONTA = db.AKONTAS.Find(id);
            if (aKONTA == null)
            {
                return BadRequest("Ne postoji A_KONTO pod tim rednim brojem");
            }

            return Ok(aKONTA);
        }
```

And In my **View** I have following

```
<br /><br />
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>A_KONTO</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="AKONTO BROJ" placeholder="Unesite broj AKONOTO">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-primary" id="aKonto" action="@Url.Action("GetAKONTA", "Akontas")">Provjeri</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

And I want to create in `btn` `click` when user pass `ID` it needs to return `XML` data format.

[image: IMAGES]

SO far I create a `JS` function, but I don't know `JavaScript` and don't know the logic how to pass `Controller Action Result` to `JS`.

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#aKonto').click(function () {
                document.getElementById("aKonto").onclick = function () {GetAKONTA()};;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

If someone can help me I would be very thankful. 
Cheers !

**UPDATE**

```
function aKontoSubmit() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'api/Akontas',
                //data: { id: id },
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (result) {
                    // action to do after form submit
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("Ne postoji AKONTO pod tim rednim brojem");
                }

            });
        }

**routeConfig**

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace AkontasWebApi
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using MVC 5?

Comment: Yes, ASP.NET MVC5

Comment: Can't you use post method in the form itself

Comment: No, because I need to call function in JS which is in my controller. It needs to work on btn click method. 
If you have any suggestion I would be very thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add Reference of Jquery, to try the ajax call method.

   ```
   function aKontoSubmit() {
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: '/Akontas/GetAKONTA',
       data: $('form').serialize(),
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (result) {
           // action to do after form submit
       },
       error: function () {
           alert("Error while inserting data");
       }
   });
   ```

   }

   2. Change you Link Code as Below

> ```
>  <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-primary" id="aKonto"  onClick='return aKontoSubmit() '>Provjeri</a>
> ```

Or Else You Can try if you are using ASP.Net MVC Core Development

```
<form asp-action="GetAKONTA" asp-controller="Akontas" method="post"> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>A_KONTO</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-describedby="AKONTO BROJ" placeholder="Unesite broj AKONOTO">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">        
         <input class="btn btn-primary" id="aKonto"  type = "submit" value = "Provjeri" /> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I get error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
Uncaught ReferenceError: aKontoSubmit is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (Index:43)

Comment: @ArualPrasth I get error when press Check button 
Failed to load resource: the server responded

Comment: @Xerror - try changing the ajax URL as Updated above. and also can you post entire code what you tried ?

Comment: Doesnt work. It seem like url needs to be /api/Akontas/{id} 
for example like this:
http://localhost:57285/api/Akontas/516005

Comment: There is problem with routing I belive

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Update your Jquery Ajax URL as like 'url:api/Akontas/GetAKONTA' and try it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199171/discussion-between-arulprasath-a-m-and-xerror).

Answer (score 0):

After a couple hours of debugging and searching I found that I forget to put

```
window.location.href = "http://localhost:57285/api/Akontas/" + $('#AkontasId').val();
```

This is location where should redirect if item exsist in database

And URL call need to be modified as well

```
URL: "/api/Akontas/GetAKONTA",


 function aKontoSubmit() {

        $.ajax({          
            type: "GET",            
            URL: "/api/Akontas/GetAKONTA",
            data: { id: $('#AkontasId').val() },
            contentType: "data/xml; charset=utf-8",  
            success: function (result) {
                window.location.href = "http://localhost:57285/api/Akontas/" + $('#AkontasId').val();
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Ne postoji AKONTO pod tim rednim brojem");
            }
        });
    }
```