# How to pass a model value to popup window in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC, you can pass values from a view to a controller. However in my case I don't want a new page. What I wish is, when I click to a button a popup window shows up and I would like to delete the record whenever I click the delete button on the popup window.

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td width="50%">
                @item.TeamName
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.TeamLeaderId
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.TeamEstablished
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-controller="Team" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="bi bi-pencil">Edit</i></a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-danger">
                    <i class="bi bi-pencil">Remove</i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Above, there is how I get the value in a foreach loop from the model. In `Remove` part, whenever user clicks on the button a popup windows shows up in the screen like this:

[image]

I need two things in here. First, instead of "Do you really want to remove **This Team**" it should be the exact team name which is 'mobileTeam' so the result should be 'Do you really want to remove **mobileTeam**'.

Second, when remove button is clicked it should trigger the post action method in controller and remove the record from database. It should pass the **id** of the team to the post action method. Here is how my post method is.

```
public IActionResult Delete(int? id)
{
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var obj = applicationDbContext.Teams.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);

        if (obj == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(obj);
}
```

This is my model popup:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            @*<button type="button" class="close" data-bs-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>*@
            <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Record</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Do you really want to remove this team?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="container">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="bi bi-pencil">Remove</i></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary " data-bs-dismiss="modal" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626885/passing-data-to-a-bootstrap-modal) question. It solves the first part of yours.
First, you should add

`data-id="@item.TeamName"`

Then, you have to add extra Javascript to your code.

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var teamName = $(e.relatedTarget).data('teamName');
    $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="teamName"]').val(teamName);
});
```

As for the API call, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57848709/call-action-method-on-button-click-asp-net-mvc)

In your case it would look something like this:

```
onClick='return DeleteTeam()'
```

At JS, do something like this:

```
function deleteTeam() {
            $.ajax({          
                type: "DELETE",            
                URL: "/api/{ControllerName}/{Endpoint}",
                data: { id: $('#TeamId').val() },
                contentType: "data/json; charset=utf-8",  
                success: function (result) {
                    window.location.href = "{yourApiAddress}" + $('#AkontasId').val();
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        }
```